# How can i read messages from IoT devices in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iot, azure-iot-hub

Package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 4.1.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1
How can I connect my IoT Hub to my Web Application?
Or maybe there is the better way to collect data from devices and send commands to them not by using asp net core application.

Comment: Well, you can still target `net45` and add it then and wait either for .NET Core 2.0 and hope that it's not using any API  `netstandard2.0` unavailable in `netstandard2.0` or until a `netstandard1.x` version is available. Of course, targeting `net45` it won't run on linux, but you'll have live with that or look for replacement. Or try running it against mono on Linux

Comment: Do you need to connect to EventHub? There is an [official library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/) compatible with .NET Standard 1.3 for that. There is also another [Service Bus .NET Standard library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) which is currently in development.

Comment: I confirm, you want to use the new libraries for Event Hub to read devices data coming into IoT Hub (we are in the processing of updating our docs online about this).